# WebMock: How to list (dump) all mocked responses?

Tags: ruby, rspec, mocking, webmock

If you make a web request in a test that isn't registered, WebMock will raise an exception, suggest how you can mock it, and list all the previously registered mocks:

[image]

I'd like to be able to dump all the registered mocks, just like the green-circled section above. How can I do that?

I've tried several invocations along these lines, without success:

```
snippet = WebMock::RequestSignatureSnippet.new(nil)
puts snippet.request_stubs
```

But I get this error on the first line:

```
 ArgumentError:
   wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1)
 # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:113:in `new'
```

While I don't understand the `wrong number of argument` error, (I am passing it a nil, afterall) I suspect I'm just barking up the wrong tree and there's a simple way to do this. I haven't found any reference in the docs or searching online.

I could duplicate code and write my own dumper, but that seems silly.

Is there a simple way to get a formatted dump of all the registered webmocks, short of making a bad network request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could check the content the [`request_stub`](https://github.com/bblimke/webmock/blob/ab85203aab16ac9ac975719b12a2608151bcce89/lib/webmock/stub_registry.rb#L17) class variable defined for `WebMock::StubRegistry`:

```
WebMock::StubRegistry.instance.request_stubs
=> [#<WebMock::RequestStub:.., ...]
```

There you can use every `RequestStub` `request_pattern` method and their content.

---

Using the `RequestSignatureSnippet`.

What you need for initializing a `RequestSignatureSnippet` object is a `RequestSignature` object, which itself, expects to receive a HTTP method (as a String) and a URI (as a String as well):

```
signature = WebMock::RequestSignature.new("GET", "http://example.com")
puts WebMock::RequestSignatureSnippet.new(signature).request_stubs
# "registered request stubs: ..."
```

Comment: Thanks, Sebastian. It's not quite as pretty as `RequestSignatureSnippet` , but `pp WebMock::StubRegistry.instance.request_stubs` does a good job of showing me what I need.

Comment: I see @DavidHempy, check the update to the answer.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you, Sebastian! :-)